# firefox extension page load not firing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, alert

I am trying to write a very simple firefox extension, that just run some basic javascript on window load. But the event never fires. I have seen and tried things from several different posts and none of them work for me.

```
function startup() {
        alert("Hi"); 
}
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

I have also tried this:

```
function startup() {
mainWindow = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)                         .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem)
                         .rootTreeItem                         .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                         .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
    mainWindow.getBrowser().addEventListener("load", listener, false);
     Sidebar is loaded and mainwindow is ready
    }

    var listener = function(e){
        alert("Hai");
        //To remove event listener
        //mainWindow.getBrowser().removeEventListener("load",listener, false);
    }
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

In both cases the red border is there on all the pages but the alert never appears.There are no errors in the debug window either. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work.

Take a look at the [borderify](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/borderify) example WebExtension. I would not be surprised if that is even the example that you were using, as it is the same `document.body.style.border = "5px solid red"` assignment.

After I modified the `borderify.js` to include your first startup function, I get the alert (and the red border) when I open https://www.mozilla.org/ (tested with Firefox 60):

```
function startup() {
  alert("Hi"); 
}
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

If you still do not see the alert, you can debug into it. The code will be executed in the content script, so you have to use the Content Script Toolbox:

1. In `about:debugging`, enable add-on debugging
2. Navigate to https://www.mozilla.org/
3. Open "Tool" -> "Web Developer" -> "Browser Content Toolbox"
4. In the debugger, open `borderify.js`

Now you can set breakpoints, and in case there are any exceptions, you will see them in the console.

Hope that helps you to narrow down the bug.